# Convert from UNIX timestamp (with milliseconds) to HH:MM:SS in Python

Tags: python, timestamp

I need to convert UNIX timestamp in miliseconds to HH:MM:SS. If I try to do this:

```
import datetime
var = 1458365220000
temp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(var).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (temp)
```

It's doesn't works, and the error I am getting is is:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is due to the milliseconds which push the number out of the range of 32-bit integers. `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` expects the first argument to be the number of **seconds** since the begin of the UNIX epoch. However, it is capable of handling fractions of a second given as floating point number. Thus, all you have to do is to divide your timestamp by 1000:

```
import datetime
var = 1458365220000
temp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(var / 1000).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (temp)
```

If you also want to include the milliseconds in your formatted string, use the following format: `'%H:%M:%S.%f'`